# Memory leak due to ByteBuffers in Netty

Tags: java, netty

I created a small Netty server to calculate the factorial of a BigInteger and send the results. The code is as follows.

Factorial.java

```
public class Factorial {

    private int port;

    public Factorial(int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }

    public void run(int threadcount) throws Exception {
        EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(threadcount);
        try {
            ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
            b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
             .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
             .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                 @Override
                 public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                     ch.pipeline().addLast(new FactorialHandler());
                 }
             })
             .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 128)          
             .childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true); 

            ChannelFuture f = b.bind(port).sync(); 

            f.channel().closeFuture().sync();
        } finally {
            workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
            bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int port = 15000;
        new Factorial(port).run(Integer.parseInt(args[0]));
    }
}
```

FactorialHandler.java

```
public class FactorialHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) { 
        BigInteger result = BigInteger.ONE;
        String resultString;
        for (int i=2000; i>0; i--)
            result = result.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
        resultString = result.toString().substring(0, 3)+"\n";
        ByteBuf buf = Unpooled.copiedBuffer(resultString.getBytes());
        ctx.write(buf);
        ctx.flush();
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
        cause.printStackTrace();
        ctx.close();
    }
}
```

When I ran this I got the following error

```
Jun 08, 2018 5:28:09 PM io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector reportTracedLeak
SEVERE: LEAK: ByteBuf.release() was not called before it's garbage-collected. See http://netty.io/wiki/reference-counted-objects.html for more information.
Recent access records:
```

As explained in the given link, I released the ByteBuffer by calling `buf.release()` in the channelRead method after `ctx.flush()`.

But when I do that, the server starts throwing the following exception

```
io.netty.util.IllegalReferenceCountException: refCnt: 0, increment: 1
```

Can someone please tell me how to fix this issue?

Comment: maybe this helps you http://netty.io/wiki/user-guide-for-4.x.html, here `Object msg` itself is released.  `@Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) { // (2)
        // Discard the received data silently.
        ((ByteBuf) msg).release(); // (3)
    } `

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is not the outbound ByteBuf. Outbound ByteBufs are always taken care of for you (See [OutboundMessages](http://netty.io/wiki/reference-counted-objects.html#outbound-messages)). The problem is the inbound ByteBuf. I'm looking at you, FactorialHandler. It extends [ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter](http://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.html). Note this from the JavaDoc:

> Be aware that messages are not released after the
>   channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext, Object) method returns
>   automatically. If you are looking for a ChannelInboundHandler
>   implementation that releases the received messages automatically,
>   please see [SimpleChannelInboundHandler](http://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/channel/SimpleChannelInboundHandler.html).

Your handler has a signature like this:

```
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg)
```

That msg, (which you don't use, by the way) is actually a ByteBuf, which is exactly what the JavaDoc note above is warning you about. (In the absence of any other ChannelHandlers, messages will always be instances of ByteBuf.)

So your options are:

1. Use a SimpleChannelInboundHandler which will clean up that reference for you.
2. At the end of your handler, release the inbound ByteBuf using [ReferenceCountUtil.release(java.lang.Object msg)](http://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/util/ReferenceCountUtil.html#release-java.lang.Object-).

Comment: Thank you @Nicholas. Adding ReferenceCountUtil.release(msg) fixed the problem

Answer (score 1):

Its because you dont call `msg.release()` (msg is an instance of ByteBuf).

Comment: Isn't result an instance of the BigInteger class?